# How to format values within the data point tooltips in a RadChart?

Tags: telerik, number-formatting, radchart

I want to format the display of numeric values in an ASP.NET RadChart's tooltips. For example, instead of showing 100000, I want the text to read "1.0e5". For the axes, the property to set is as follows:

```
chart.InnerChart.PlotArea.YAxis.Appearance.CustomFormat = "0.##E+0";
```

There must be a similar property on the chartSeries to similarly format the tooltips, but so far I have failed to locate it. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each ChartSeriesItem in the chart, you can set the ToolTip in the following manner:

```
e.SeriesItem.ActiveRegion.Tooltip = string.Format("{0:0.###e+0}", value);
```

Comment: Congratulations, you found it. That's worth a +1. However, it seems like a brute force way to have to do it.

Comment: Indeed, I agree. Pls let me know if you think of a better way. Likewise, I'll post one if I can think it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which RadChart you are using. Here is an excerpt of code for an ASP.Net MVC RadChart.

```
.Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
    .Visible(true)
    .Format("{0:0.##E+0}")
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I'm using the ASP.NET web forms version. But I think your snippet adjusts the single tooltip for the chart itself, not the many tooltips for all of the series points. I looked and there is no Tooltip property for ChartSeriesItem. Surely there must be a way.

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC, the code above formats the tooltips for all the series points. I will look at the web forms version to see if I can find anything similar.